# Django command fails when run by Cron

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, cron

I have a custom django management command in my crontab:

```
0 0 * * * cd /home/django/dataprocessing/ && /usr/bin/python manage.py import
```

This command runs successfully when I run it manually but when run by Cron fails on this line:

```
output = subprocess.check_output("aws s3 ls s3://content/{}".format(filename))
```

There is no error, the process simply stops. I have determined that this is the point of failure after extensive debugging. I've seen a couple of similar issues but nothing that has worked for me. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Have you tried capturing stdout and stderr? Append `&> import.log`. It may be something environment related such as AWS credentials.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to give the full location of aws

```
s3=["""/usr/local/bin/aws""" + " s3 cp --region " + file_name + "s3://<bucket>"]
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! This came to me to review as it is your first post - thanks for answering. There are a couple of things you could do to improve the answer with respect to the [site's answering guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  Could you give a little more context to your answer?  Where should this full location be placed to solve the OP's issue?  If the line "s3=["""/usr/local/bin/aws""" + " s3 cp --region " + file_name + "s3://"]" is Python code, please use the site's markdown to format it as code.